# Windows Mobile local database

Tags: c#, database, windows-mobile, mobile

I'm writing an application for windows mobile 6 and above that requires a local database.

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with database hosting on windows mobile and which database management system would be most suitable for development.

Thanks in advance,

Lloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [SqlServerCe](http://www.microsoft.com/downlOAds/details.aspx?familyid=38ED2670-A70A-43B3-87F3-7AB67B56CBF2&displaylang=en) as a local mini database for a WinMobile 6 application I've worked on. It is quite easy to use and gets automatically installed when you include the reference in Visual Studio.

Another option that seems popular is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). For a comparison of the two look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583278/sqlite-vs-sqlce-vs-in-a-mobile-application
This seems to be biased towards SQLite which I have not tried but I was happy with the performance of SqlServerCe for my application and it was sufficient.

Comment: The latest version of SQL Server Compact Edition is a wholesale improvement over the prior versions, definitely worth a look - (somewhat) works with LINQ to SQL as well, a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) is widely used in Windows Mobile applications.

Another alternative is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to RDBMS, you should try [db4o](http://www.db4o.com), an embedded object oriented database with support for LINQ

Comment: Performance issues should be considered, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used for some small applications Raima Database, and it proved to be reliable and fast, at least for our purposes.